# ORA-06502, ORA-06512 Oracle stored procedure error

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

These are the errors I am getting when I try to execute the stored procedure from my c# code.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "MYAPP.PRO_COMPANYSEARCH", line 28
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

My c# code looks like this:

```
using (var mCon = new OracleConnection(MyConnectionString))
{
    myCon.Open();

    using (OracleCommand myOracleCmd = myCon.CreateCommand())
    {
        myOracleCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myOracleCmd.CommandText = "PRO_COMPANYSEARCH";
        myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_result_cur", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_sqlcode", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
        myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_sqlmsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);

        var reader = myOracleCmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtCompany.Load(reader);
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

There are 3 output parameters, 2 of which are used for tracking exceptions and the other one for the result.

EDIT: This is my stored procedure, (cant believe I forgot to post it)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PRO_COMPANYSEARCH (
    o_result_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    o_sqlcode OUT NUMBER,
    o_sqlmsg OUT VARCHAR2)

IS
BEGIN
  o_sqlmsg  := 'SUCCESS';
  o_sqlcode := 0;
  OPEN o_result_cur FOR Select distinct irint, irname, irabbv, iropt From vw_issue;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  o_sqlcode := SQLCODE * -1;
  o_sqlmsg  := 'NO DATA FOUND';
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  o_sqlcode := SQLCODE * -1;     --This is line 28, I removed unnecessary comments.
  o_sqlmsg  := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
END PRO_COMPANYSEARCH;
```

Comment: I'm guessing line 28 of your stored procedure would probably help identify the issue.

Comment: I posted the stored procedure.

Comment: I doubt that is the problem line.  Run a standalone test by calling the procedure from a pl/sql block and see if you still get an error.

Comment: when I run the stored procedure in sql developer it works fine, and runs the query.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the answer, in the c# code you have to include the size of the varchar also

```
using (var mCon = new OracleConnection(MyConnectionString))
{
    myCon.Open();

    using (OracleCommand myOracleCmd = myCon.CreateCommand())
    {
        myOracleCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myOracleCmd.CommandText = "PRO_COMPANYSEARCH";
        myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_result_cur", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_sqlcode", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
        myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_sqlmsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
        myOracleCmd.Parameters["O_sqlmsg"].Size = 255;

        myOracleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var myReader = ((OracleRefCursor)myOracleCmd.Parameters["o_result_cur"].Value).GetDataReader();


        dtCompany.Load(myReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also write in one line `myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_sqlmsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255, null, ParameterDirection.Output);`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you they way you suggested works with me ... just as feedback for others

Comment: A minor note here: take care to use the **five-parameter** method overload. I used the four-parameter one that went `myOracleCmd.Parameters.Add("o_sqlmsg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255, ParameterDirection.Output);` and it didn't work. Make sure to put ˙null˙ at parameter #4.

Comment: You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the above answer amends little.

```
var output_result_string = new OracleParameter("OUTPUT_RESULT_STRING", 
OracleDbType.NVarchar2, xxx, ParameterDirection.Output);
output_result_string.Size = 2500;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleDbConnector().OracleConnection)

using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "MyFunction";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("returnVal", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    cmd.Parameters["returnVal"].Size = 200;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("application", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "InputValue", ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string returnValue = cmd.Parameters["returnVal"].Value.ToString();
}
```